# How can I get the 1's and 0's binary code of an audio file? (Python)

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to figure out how I can convert .mp3 files into pure binary code in text. I'd like to be able to use the binary 1's and 0's for a separate project of mine.
I'm still pretty new to Python so this is what I did manage to find on this so far:

```
import os
os.chdir('filepath')
b=BitArray(bytes=open('filename.mp3','rb').read())
print(b.read())
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue, add that as well

Comment: Also which Python version are you using? Which package are you using from BitArray?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I'd like to find out better strategies for doing this. I'm not exactly the most well-versed in coding, my speciality is in genetics. I want to convert audio into the genomic sequence and be able to decrypt it as well (.dna files). Someone on reddit mentioned this but I've no idea on how to approach it: "In that case you don't need to convert to binary-as-text first - you can use bitwise operations, or you can even precompute a lookup table for every byte value."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to `b.bin` to get the bit string and then store it to a text file.

```py
import os
from bitstring import BitArray

os.chdir('filepath')
b=BitArray(bytes=open('filename.mp3','rb').read())

# Store result
with open('filename_bits.txt', 'w') as file1: 
    file1.write(b.bin)
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! This code did definitely help, although all of the outputs are connected into a single strain. Is there a way to perhaps separate the characters?